# Retain selected value from drop down list in html

Tags: html, css, angularjs, combobox

I have a drop down list in my application from which I can select the options. Currently the selected option is updated in sql database but when I reopen the page the value doesn't show up in html page. Is there anything else to be added in my html code?

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-model="vm.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required" tooltip-placement="top" required tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">
            <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
            <option value="Unsatisfactory">Unsatisfactory</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

i update the value

[image]

after reopening the page for edit selected value doesn't show up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the drop down value in controller after getting saved value from database

```
$scope.Quality = //something got from databse;
```